# The Watchers in Judaism

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, tanach

My wife asked me if there were any opinions that the B'nei Elohim that slept with the daughters of men were actually angels. In one of her Torah commentaries it said there was no such opinion. I showed her the Book of Jubilees which mentioned these Watchers as being a specific set of Angels, and the commentary made reference to the Watchers being discussed more in the book of Enoch

Jubilees and Enoch while not canonical, were definitely plentifully studied in their times and we see Hebrew/Aramaic versions in the Dead Sea Scrolls.

My question is do we have any commentators after Jubilees/Enoch who claim these B'nei Elohim  are these "Watchers"?

Comment: The Rashi translation [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.6.2.1?lang=bi) translates השרים as "princely angels," but that seems like a misinterpretation. See [Levush Haorah](https://www.sefaria.org/Levush_HaOrah%2C_Genesis.6.2.1), [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Genesis.6.2.1) and [Shadal](https://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Genesis.6.2.1).

Comment: Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer and Zohar say they were angels: http://www.aspaklaria.info/002_BET/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%20%20%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D.htm

Comment: look up a Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok, the watchers  were angels who indeed mated with human woman and they gave birth to nephalim.  But another opinion says they were simply the mighty men of the time.  If you read the book of Daniel it says Gabriel was hindered by the angel of Persia.  This Angel was a watcher, they also made the king of Babylon go insane.  Also it seems to me you are Christian, Judaism does not have “canonical” books.  The 5 Books of Moses are the sacred Torah, the other books  were later added but there were many books that were not added

Comment: I did answer you and gave you a link to an expert in the field.  Don’t worry next time you need assistance I won’t answer as you feel my answers aren’t good enough.  Second no one called you a Christian

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. You posted a link about the Watchers and Rosh Hashannah. I'm not debating the authenticity of Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok. But you could have stated "According to Rabbi Tzadok the watchers are x,y,z here's a Rosh Hashanna themed video discussing." I encourage you to write another answer that fits a bit more in line with how answers are usually done. Please don't take my critique as reason for you not to participate in this site